# CoreData and UITableView: display values in cells

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I'm working with Core Data and web service, I want to add my data to my table,
but I don't know how should I call them, would you please help me, since when I used this way it's not working.

Here is my method for update database in my HTTP class

```
- (void)updateLocalCardsDataBase:(NSArray*) cardsArray
{
    //check if current user has cards in local database
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    for(NSDictionary *cardDic in cardsArray)
    {
        Card *card = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        card.remote_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[cardDic objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
        card.stampNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[cardDic objectForKey:@"stampNumber"] intValue]];
        card.createdAt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[cardDic objectForKey:@"createdAt"] intValue]];

        [managedObjectContext lock];
        NSError *error;
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
            if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
            for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
                NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
    [managedObjectContext unlock];
}
```

Here is my table:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    // NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CardsCell";
    CardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in objects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (CardCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    NSDictionary *f = [_cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.stampId.text = [f objectForKey:@"stampNumber"];
    NSLog(@"%@fdssfdfddavds",[f objectForKey:@"stampNumber"]);
    cell.createdAt.text = [f objectForKey:@"createdAt"];
    cell.CardId.text = [f objectForKey:@"id"];
    return cell;
}
```

Edit:

**My problem is how I can show data in a `UITableView`**

Comment: What is the problem? Are you asking how get a list of your Core Data objects?

Comment: @MikeD I want to show my stampId,createdAt, CardId in uitableview but I don't know how

Comment: how are you populating `_cards`?

Comment: @MikeD it's my problem I think I have to use fetched

Comment: Yes. You have have use a fetch request.

Comment: @MikeD would you please help me I don\t know where should I used that

Comment: I am working on an answer now, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Before call `[tableView reloadData]`, you need to get a data source first. You will get back an array of your data models, **not** an `NSDictionary`. You can place the my example method (or a variation that suits you best) where ever best suits your needs, but this one will not filter or sort the models, it will only get all of them. Also, I will place the method in your view controller that stores the table view:

```
-(NSArray*)getMycards {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSError *error;

    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSArray *cards = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // now check if there is an error and handle it appropriatelty
    // I usually return 'nil' but you don't have if you don't want
    if ( error != nil ) {
        // investigate error
    }
    return cards;
}
```

I recommend creating a property `@property NSArray *cards` in the view controller where you place your table, it will be easier to manage. One assumption I have made (since I have no other information about your view controller, a property named 'tableView' is declared in your view controller's header file (`@property UITableView *tableView;`), adjust the naming as needed.

With the above method, when you want to populate your array before loading the table's data:

```
// you put this block of code anywhere in the view controller that also has your table view
// likely in 'viewDidLoad' or 'viewDidAppear'
// and/or anywhere else where it makes sense to reload the table
self.cards = [self getMyCards];
if ( self.cards.count > 0 )
    [self.tableview reloadData];
else {
   // maybe display an error
}
```

Now, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should look like

```
-(UITableViewCell*tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath {
    UITbaleViewCell *cell = ...;
    // creating the type of cell seems fine to me
    .
    .
    .
    // keep in mind I don't know the exact make up of your card model
    // I don't know what the data types are, so you will have to adjust as necessary
    Card *card = self.cards[indexPath.row];

    cell.stampId.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",card.stamp];
    cell.createdAt.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",card.createdAt];
    // you might want format the date property better, this might end being a lot more than what you want
    cell.CardId.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",card.id];

    return cell;
}
```

Core Data is extremely powerful, I highly recommend the [Core Data overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005316), followed by the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Comment: thanks Where should I put self.cards = [someclass getMyCards];
if ( self.cards.count > 0 )
    [self.tableview reloadData];
else {
   // maybe display an error
}?

Comment: @Miek D again thank you for your help, I have still question about this part :  self.cards = [someclass getMyCards];
if ( self.cards.count > 0 )
    [self.tableview reloadData];
else {
   // maybe display an error
}  what do you mean by this part -> someclass and also I have error for this self.tableview  since I used ViewController class

Comment: @adam Updated. 'someClass' meant you can put the fetch request anywhere you want, I changed so it is in your view controller. I made the assumption you are storing the table view in a property named `tableView`. You can adjust the naming as you need to.

Comment: can I put my Fetches staff in -(void) updateLocalCardsDataBase:(NSArray*) cardsArray method?

Comment: Yes you can, but you will have to make sure you link properly to the table's data source.

Comment: @adam let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25622/discussion-between-mike-d-and-adam)